# me redirecciona de forma incorrecta en htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

Este es mi código, para realizar una redirección 301:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código si redirecciona, sin embargo cuando redirige me resulta de esta forma:

https://www.paginanueva.com.pe/comunicado-a-nuestros-vecinos/?/articulos/227/comunicado-vecinos-nuevos

como ven en la ruta, esta agregando este pedazo adicional "**?/articulos/227/comunicado-vecinos-nuevos**" que no debería, porque el resultado correcto debería ser esto:

https://www.paginanueva.com.pe/comunicado-a-nuestros-vecinos/

Por favor alguna sugerencia.

Gracias

Comment: Agrega el código del .htaccess a tu pregunta para que la comunidad pueda ver

Comment: ya agregue la imagen del código